# EVM Storage Architecture

Tags: solidity

I am doing a research about, how the smart contract works with the storage, the pointers, and all about storage in evm. Would you recommend me the better reading about it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For a more pragmatic approach I'd start by reading [Diving Into The Ethereum Virtual Machine](https://blog.qtum.org/diving-into-the-ethereum-vm-6e8d5d2f3c30) by Howard. There are several chapters dedicated explain how solidity primitives like array, string, mapping are represented in the contract storage.